# Are there existing term(s) for a 1-1 child-parent table anti-pattern?

Tags: database-design, anti-patterns, normalization

**NOTE**: Please don't respond by telling me that I probably don't understand what I am looking at.  You can't possibly know that and it's wrong.  Just don't answer if that's all you have to say.

I'm looking for a term akin to the "N+1 problem" but for a different issue.
I know that the term 'anti-pattern' may raise some hackles but I'm pretty certain that the approach described below is either an implementation error or comes from some fundamental misunderstandings about database normalization.  If anyone can explain any legitimate reason for doing this, I'd love to read it.

Background: I'm doing some analysis on a complex database defined by a 3rd-party.  I keep finding an odd pattern (in the general sense) to the way that the parent-child relationships are populated with data.

I thought of a concrete example of this style:

```
---------------
| date        |     
---------------     ---------------
| PK          |     | day_of_week |
| date        |     ---------------
| day_of_week | --> | PK          |
| data ...    |     | number      |
---------------     | name        |
                    | weekend     |
                    ---------------
```

OK. Looks like a relatively typical normalized structure.  But when I look at the data in the tables, I find something puzzling:

```
------------------------------      -----------------------------
|            date            |      |       day_of_week         |
-----------------------------|      -----------------------------
| PK | date     | dow | data |      | PK | num | name  | wkend  |
------------------------------      -----------------------------
| 1  | 23-05-28 | 1   | bcd  |      | 1  | 1   | sun   | true   |
| 2  | 23-05-29 | 2   | cde  |      | 2  | 2   | mon   | false  |
| 3  | 23-05-30 | 3   | def  |      | 3  | 3   | tue   | false  |
| 4  | 23-05-31 | 4   | efg  |      | 4  | 4   | wed   | false  |
| 5  | 23-06-01 | 5   | fgh  |      | 5  | 5   | thurs | false  |
| 6  | 23-06-02 | 6   | ghi  |      | 6  | 6   | fri   | false  |
| 7  | 23-06-03 | 7   | hij  |      | 7  | 7   | sat   | true   |
| 8  | 23-06-04 | 8   | ijk  |      | 8  | 1   | sun   | true   |
| 9  | 23-06-05 | 9   | jkl  |      | 9  | 2   | mon   | false  |
| 10 | 23-06-06 | 10  | klm  |      | 10 | 3   | tue   | false  |
| 11 | 23-06-07 | 11  | lmn  |      | 11 | 4   | wed   | false  |
| 12 | 23-06-08 | 12  | mno  |      | 12 | 5   | thurs | false  |
| 13 | 23-06-09 | 13  | nop  |      | 13 | 6   | fri   | false  |
| 14 | 23-06-10 | 14  | opq  |      | 14 | 7   | sat   | true   |
| 15 | 23-06-11 | 15  | pqr  |      | 15 | 1   | sun   | true   |
|... |...       |     |...   |      |... | ... | ...   | ...    |
```

In some cases that I've dug into a small set of unique data values in the reference table can make up than half of the rows (or more) in the reference table.  The repeated data values are literally identical.  I am seeing this in many places in the DB.  Sometimes there are multiple tables pointing to the reference table and again, there's a separate entry for each dependent row regardless of whether that reference data already exists.

I don't know the full scope of this, but I believe a significant portion of the DB storage is being used to store these redundant rows.  In addition, the inserts associated with these reference rows could be adding significant load.  Both the storage requirements and performance of this system are problematic.

Is this something that has a name?  I can think of a few choice terms for this.  'Doing it wrong' is one on the more polite end of the spectrum.  Does 'anti-normalization' make sense?  It's not really de-normalized.  It's more of a normalization face-plant.  'Normalization face-plant' would be a fun term but doesn't sound professional.

I've seen this happen in systems I was involved in due to incorrect implementation.  The problem I have is that the 3rd-party makes a habit of dismissing such critiques by saying that my team "doesn't understand" the solution.  It's not clear whether they actually believe this or if they are simply using it as a strategy.  It would like to be able to point to an independent source confirming this is not a good approach so I can avoid a time-consuming, frustrating and potentially fruitless debate.

Comment: Did you ask them if they can explain why the system is designed like this? Can you share their response?

Comment: @RikD I haven't yet.  I have a strong suspicion that it's related to hand-rolling your own ORM.  One of my colleagues had to fight for months, write up a paper and involve executives to get them to fix something roughly as obvious (and easier to fix.)  I want to be prepared because it's really hard to keep it cool when they are so disrespectful and wrong at the same time.

Comment: Two columns being trivially functionally dependent *by design* is an obvious anti-pattern (easily fixed with computed columns though). But breaking a big table up, can be a simple case of vertical partitioning to avoid juggling all the extra columns you often don't need.

Comment: @Deduplicator In one example. there's 6 data columns on the ref table and 4-9 on the the children.  The FK is required in all the child tables I've checked.  Regardless, why wouldn't you remove the duplicates?  Why not reference the existing rows instead of doing an insert on the parent for every child insert?

Comment: @candied_orange As I said the storage costs for this system are a real problem. It's possible that this extra data could cost more per year than employing several full-time senior engineers.

Comment: @JimmyJames I'll make one last attempt to tease apart these two issues. If every `parent.data` field was unique would you have any issue with `main` & `parent` having this 1 to 1 relationship?

Comment: @candied_orange Not really, it still wouldn't justifiable for such narrow tables, though.

Comment: Especially given that in some cases the PK is many orders of magnitude larger than the data on these ref tables.

Comment: In the example data, shouldn’t the table on the right be `ref` instead of `parent`?

Comment: @JimmyJames any chance you can speak with dev teams using these tables? Or, maybe, an SCM you can look for commits or documentation? There should be a DDL and a DML somewhere (scripts to create and populate the DB). The DB might tell you a story and apps a very different one.

Comment: @Laiv Unfortunately no, these tables and the system that uses them are defined by a 3rd-party.  They are hosted on our (expensive) resources, though.

Comment: What information is missing? That I know what I am doing?  How do I get you to stop questioning the question?

Comment: @JimmyJames, I'm afraid without more meaningful table and column names, it's going to be hard or impossible to say.  For a second, I was thinking about some sort of historical (`main` pointing to data and `ref` holding historical values). If you find auditory columns or version control numbers then there's a chance. Another option is buggy code or flawed app designs. If you can't find a pattern in the data (and 500M rows are too much data for you to look for patterns), I would arrange a call with the 3rd party asap to understand what's going on.

Comment: @IMSoP Let me ask you this: imagine if you had table person, with millions of entries and there's are 3 person types with a set of values that have exactly three permutations in the millions of rows.  You are asked to normalize the table so you create a person_type table.  How many rows would you make person_type have?

Comment: @IMSoP An explanation for a legitimate technical reason for doing this, not an explanation that asserts that I'm a dumbass.

Comment: @Laiv Athough you say that the example isn't enough, you are right on track.  I don't want to get into the actual table names or columns because that would make if too obvious what this is but, versioning is part of the equation (and a likely root cause) but it doesn't explain it.  First of all, almost all of the 'versions' are all the same value.  But the child table is also versioned.  The child version and the parent version are 1-to-1 so a new parent version is created for each child version regardless of whether the parent value changed.

Comment: "If you can't find a pattern in the data (and 500M rows are too much data for you to look for patterns)," I'm not sure what you mean.  I'm pretty good with SQL and I can see some really clear patterns such as nearly 100 million of the 500 million rows have exactly the same data values.

Comment: @Laiv There are lots of relationships like this but one example (not real names) would be main->error and ref->message, where the errors are generated by automated processing.  There's an entry in message for every error row.  The most common error is nearly 100 million of the rows.  The second most common error is nearly 100 million of the rows. They are exactly the same.  They never change.

Comment: For a second, I thought about immutability and the second after in your DB as a heap dump. Now I'm puzzled too.

Comment: @Laiv Right.  There's some really strange stuff.  Like a reference table where all the data consists entirely of small integers.  No associated data.  Half a dozen values but hundreds of thousands of rows.

Comment: @Laiv I do know that there's some sort of custom code generation involved.  I'm 100% this is an error of some sort.  I just wish I had a name for it, similar to the "N+1 problem."  Coincidentally, some of the query performance analysis suggested that there was N+1 queries but now I'm thinking that may be a outcome of the way the data is structured.

Comment: @JimmyJames The new illustration explains the issue much better. Clarifying questions: What is the "data" column? Do other tables in the database have foreign-key relationships to the depicted tables?

Comment: The data label is meant to represent various other columns that are not related to the FK to the lookup table.  This pattern repeats across many relationships and is sometimes layered.  Another relevant fact is that these lookup tables are usually referenced by multiple tables but none of the child tales appear to point to the same rows on the lookups (leading to more duplicate data in the lookup.)

Comment: To that last point, it's a pretty terrible approach.  Part of the point of using a shared lookup table is that you can do things like easily join the child tables by the foreign key.  But in this DB, you can't do that.  You have to first join to the lookup on all the child tables and then join those results by value.   It's like running the ball down right to the goal and then kicking it out-of-bounds.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Anti-normalization** it is then.  I'm still open to other names.

JacquesB suggested "violation of the 3rd-normal form" but I don't think that really captures how insanely stupid this is or how bad the impact is on the performance of the DB and application.

Answer (score 8):

*Answer after the question was edited:*

There are several issues with the depicted data. The most serious is a violation of *third normal form* in the second table, since weekday-name and weekend-flag will always be the same for a given weekday number - but weekday number is not a unique for the table. Therefore weekday-name and weekend flag should be extracted to a separate lookup table.

There is arguably a redundancy in even storing weekday number for each date, since weekday can be algorithmically determined from the date. But this is not strictly a violation of normalization, and storing the weekday may be justified for practical reasons.

Then there is a 1:1 relationship between the two tables depicted. This is not strictly a violation of normalization either, but problematic since it makes inserts more complex and has a cost in joins. 1:1 relationships are sometimes used deliberately in a pattern called vertical partitioning or row splitting, but then the partitions usually share the same primary key. Unless other tables in the database have a foreign key to the second table, the partitioning does not seem useful.

I don't think there is a common term covering these issues, except the rater general "redundant data". But the violation of 3rd normal form in itself should be enough to request a redesign of the schema.

Violation of normalization is typically due to bad database design, but in some cases it may be deliberate for performance reasons. Especially in databases designed for analytics (rather than OLTP) like in data-warehouses, denormalization and row-splitting is often used to optimize certain analysis.

It could also just be that the second table is a mistaken attempt to create a lookup table.

---

*Original answer:*

What you see is called **vertical partitioning** or **row splitting** or **sixth normal form**.

Having repeated values in a column is not in itself problematic. E.g. if you have a boolean column you will have lots of repeated values, but this is perfectly fine.

Having 1:1 tables (as this example seem to be) does not violate normalization. But from a practical perspective, it is more inconvenient for queries and updates than just having a single table. But there *may* be practical considerations which offset this inconvenience. Some I can think of:

- Performance: In some cases performance can be increased by vertical
  partitioning of tables.
- Organization or permissions: The columns may "belong" to different
  applications or departments and have different access rights.

It might also be that the data is actually one-to-many, but just one-to-one in most cases. E.g. most people have one nationality, but a small fraction has multiple.

Bottom line: You have to bite the bullet and ask the person who designed this for the reason. You should be open to the possibility that it is designed like that for a good reason.

It sounds like you are searching for a justification to dismiss this design without needing to understand the rationale first. And the other party says you "don't understand" the solution. Honestly, it seems more of a peoples or communication issue rather than a database design issue.

Comment: Explain to me how having hundreds of millions of rows with the exact same data values improves performance for joins.  Consider indexes and inserts.  Why would joining the child rows to a single parent row be less performant?

Comment: @JimmyJames: It is called vertical partitioning or row splitting or 6th normal form, if you want to look further into it. It can in some cases increase performance e.g if queries often scan and select from some columns significantly much more than others. But it very much depends on the particular database and workload if there is any benefit.

Comment: Can you address the question I asked?  E.g.: How is joining a thousand rows to a thousand rows going to be better/faster than joining 1000 rows to 6 rows?  The results will be identical.

Comment: @JimmyJames: I doubt it would be faster. But I think you are conflating different issues with this question. Vertical partitioning does not increase or decrease the number of rows, it increases the number of tables. But if you are talking about extracting duplicate values in a column to a lookup table, that would just introduce a join. E.g. imagine you have a boolean column and then extract the two values to lookup-table with two rows - you would still need a FK to the lookup-table for each row in the main table. This would introduce a join you may not need.

Comment: I am nof conflating the issue, you are referring to something irrelevant to the situation at hand.  "But if you are talking about extracting duplicate values in a column to a lookup table, that would just introduce a join."  Right, which is what this is all about.

Comment: @JimmyJames OK, if I understand correctly, you are not really concerned about the vertical partitioning of the table into multiple 1:1 tables, you are concerned about the duplicate values in some columns? Duplicate values are not problematic as long as the data is otherwise normalized. If you changed the duplicate values to foreign keys to a smaller lookup table you would just get duplicate foreign keys in the main table.

Comment: I'm sorry but have you actually read the question? "Duplicate values are not problematic as long as the data is otherwise normalized."  OK, so if you normalized some columns into a reference table, how many duplicate values would you expect in the reference table?  For example, let's say I have a 'days of the week' table, how many rows should it have?

Comment: @JimmyJames Let's say you have a table with a million persons, a row for each, with a column indicating the day of the week they were born. OK so you have lots of duplicates in this row, since there are only seven days of the week. Now you extract the day of the week to a separate table with seven rows, and instead use the column as foreign key to this new table. You still have exactly the same number of duplicates in that column.

Comment: So 7 rows, not 700K?

Comment: @JimmyJames If you need to associate a day-of-the-week with 700K entities (and there are no non-key functional dependencies otherwise), then you would need a column with 700K values. If you add a lookup table for the seven possible values, then you would need 700K + 7 rows in all.

Comment: @JimmyJames So the be clear, it is not a question of *either* 700 K values or just 7 values. If you need to add information to 700 K entities, you need a column of 700 K rows either way, regardless of the size of the data type, The 7 rows in a lookup table would be *in addition* to that.

Comment: So, you think it would be normal to have 700K rows in a days of the week table with only 7 distinct rows (aside from the primary key)?  Is that how *you* normalize data?

Comment: I don't know what else to tell you to get you to understand that the 700K rows are **in the lookup table**.

Comment: @JimmyJames if the two tables are 1:1 then it is not a lookup table, it is a vertical partition. Lookup tables and vertical portions are independent concerns - you can have both, a vertical partition *and* a lookup table for the unique values. Or you can have either, or none. Perhaps you think the vertical partition was supposed to be a lookup table but just badly designed? This is of course possible but probably more likely it is deliberate use of vertical partitioning.

Comment: I don't thing you are following.  Thanks for trying.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/146425/discussion-between-jacquesb-and-jimmyjames).

Comment: "Unless other tables in the database have a foreign key to the second table, the partitioning does not seem useful." There are foreign keys to these tables from other tables.  Some of these have a dozen or more tables referencing them but AFAICT, they never share any rows.  That is, if there were twelve tables using the same data values (e.g. Saturday of week), there are separate rows each usage from each table i.e. child A and child B never have an FK to the same row.

Comment: This isn't helping performance in any way.   It's objectively and empirically a major performance drag.  Consider how this affects caching.  On the client there is a huge cache (high memory use) which accomplishes almost nothing for these tables (because no rows are reused across lookups).  On the DB, it causes the LRU cache to constantly churn.

Comment: "There is arguably a redundancy in even storing weekday number for each date, since weekday can be algorithmically determined from the date."  Don't get hung up on the example, it's not literally what they are doing but a very good approximation of the 'approach'.  There's an instance of one of these tables that has a PK and an int column consisting of only positive single digit ints.  There are hundreds of thousands of rows with the value 3.  There's no reason that the child tables couldn't have used the value 3 directly instead holding the key (e.g. 955529).  This is OLTP BTW.

Comment: "My ugly car wont start" "You need to paint it" "How's that going to help?" "It wont be so ugly".

Answer (score 2):

> If anyone can explain any legitimate reason for doing this, I'd love to read it.

Well...

> **1 to 0..1**
> The "1 to 0..1" between super and sub-classes is used as a part of "all classes in separate tables" strategy for implementing inheritance.
>
> A "1 to 0..1" can be represented in a single table with "0..1" portion covered by NULL-able fields. However, if the relationship is mostly "1 to 0" with only a few "1 to 1" rows, splitting-off the "0..1" portion into a separate table might save some storage (and cache performance) benefits. Some databases are thriftier at storing NULLs than others, so a "cut-off point" where this strategy becomes viable can vary considerably.
>
> [Stack Overflow - When I Should Use One To One Relationship](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12318870/when-i-should-use-one-to-one-relationship)

You may be thinking: I don't see that.

You don't see that, yet. Remember, you said "any".

> **1 to 1**
> The real "1 to 1" vertically partitions the data, which may have implications for caching. Databases typically implement caches at the page level, not at the level of individual fields, so even if you select only a few fields from a row, typically the whole page that row belongs to will be cached. If a row is very wide and the selected fields relatively narrow, you'll end-up caching a lot of information you don't actually need. In a situation like that, it may be useful to vertically partition the data, so only the narrower, more frequently used portion or rows gets cached, so more of them can fit into the cache, making the cache effectively "larger".
>
> Another use of vertical partitioning is to change the locking behavior: databases typically cannot lock at the level of individual fields, only the whole rows. By splitting the row, you are allowing a lock to take place on only one of its halfs.
>
> Triggers are also typically table-specific. While you can theoretically have just one table and have the trigger ignore the "wrong half" of the row, some databases may impose additional limits on what a trigger can and cannot do that could make this impractical. For example, Oracle doesn't let you modify the mutating table - by having separate tables, only one of them may be mutating so you can still modify the other one from your trigger.
>
> Separate tables may allow more granular security.
>
> These considerations are irrelevant in most cases, so in most cases you should consider merging the "1 to 1" tables into a single table.
>
> [Stack Overflow - When I Should Use One To One Relationship](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12318870/when-i-should-use-one-to-one-relationship)

And I'll add one: time.  The data looks like this today but tomorrow it might well look different. Office databases can go years before the first time someone has a second home address associated with them. You won't see the need for that in day one data.

As for a name, I'd call it "an unjustified 1 to 1 relationship" and invite them to justify it. If they're telling you that you don't understand just ask them to explain it.  The world has enough IT mysteries.

As for the dupes in the parent table, the only justification I can think of is this is a table for data entry. People just type in a field and nothing checks for dupes. You could dedupe but if you do when they come back and change it to something unique you'd have to give it new row all over again.

It may be the DB optimizes this for you silently in the background. I know Java does short string optimization which is why we have to use `.equals()` not `==`. Who knows what the modern DBs are up to.

Comment: This doesn't make sense.  Breaking up the table and keeping 100's of millions of duplicate rows (aside from surrogate keys) are two completely different things.  What would you imagine prevents them from pointing two child rows to the same parent?

Comment: @JimmyJames Apart from the apps business rules nothing. But just because the existing data doesn't point two children at the same parent doesn't mean the app has a business rule not to point two children at one parent. Just means it hasn't happened yet.

Comment: "Just means it hasn't happened yet" Exactly, that's the problem.  Why hasn't it happened yet?  Maybe after the 100 millionth row with exactly the same data is inserted, one of those rows (0.000001%) will be reused.  Problem solved!

Comment: I don't think I'm making this clear. It isn't about the number of rows. It's about if the data represents the results of every use case yet.

Comment: "It may be the DB optimizes this for you silently in the background." No.   I am looking at the table.  It has over 500 million rows which each have a separate PK value.  "have to give it new row all over again."  Yes, that's a better solution than adding the same values 100 million times.

Comment: @JimmyJames yes but if that's happening at a lower level you'd never see it.

Comment: Sorry, I really have no idea what you are talking about. What difference does it make if every use case is represented?  You don't need 100 million rows to represent 6 small values in a DB.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/146392/discussion-between-candied-orange-and-jimmyjames).

Comment: Actually, in Java the string literal optimization is why == works sometimes with strings.  It has nothing to do with why you should use equals().